# Cant get Query params in Hashlocation strategy in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, angular-routing, hash-location-strategy

I am using a hash location strategy in Angular

*routing.module.ts*

```
@NgModule({ 
imports: [
   RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })
 ],
 exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
})
```

*app.module.ts*

```
@NgModule({
    providers: [{ provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy }]
})
```

I am routing from some other application to my angular application with this URL

```
HTTP://localhost:4200?param_x=xyz&param_y=abc
```

I want to get values of these params in my application, how do I do that?

I tried using Activated route snapshot as well as subscribe, both give me empty values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please open your client side with fragment params.

Fragment params are parameters after # - also called as client params because they arent sent to the server.

```
HTTP://localhost:4200?#hash_param_x=xyz&hash_param_y=abc
```

Then access them via:

```
this.activatedRoute.snapshot.queryParams
```

`HashLocationStrategy`  takes the hash(fragment/client) params and insert them into query params. Since you don't have any, you don't see any params.

Comment: I have both scenarios, I am redirected to the angular application with my params from the server and I want to use those.

apart from that, I use the params internally within the application.

Comment: So open your client side with fragment params and not query ones. Does this work for you? Once you open it one time, you shouldn't be bothered with anymore.

Comment: I updated my answer to reflect that. After inital redirect there's no need for extra work. You can use snapshot.queryParams all the way.

Comment: Worked perfectly for me! Thanks