# Character '#' in web url returns location.search empty

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

**Background:**

I have recently published my angular project on **namecheap** hosting. Due to routing issues, I have enabled `useHash = true` while exporting my `app-routing.ts` file.

```
export const appRoutingModule = RouterModule.forRoot(routes,{ enableTracing: false, useHash: true});
```

Since, my routing issues resolved, however in all my URL's I got #.

**Issue:**

At one point in my code, I access the URL and analyze the URL, if there is already a search query parameter I append the new one with `&` symbol or if there is not then I add the search query with `?` sign.

```
        var uid = this.route.snapshot;
        var searchURL = "";
        
     
        alert("Checking search:: " + window.location.search); // returns empty
        alert("One more time:: " + new URLSearchParams(location.search)); // returns empty 
        if (new URL(window.location.href).search == "")
        {
          searchURL = "?"+incomingSearch;
        }
        else 
        {
          searchURL = new URL(window.location.href).search + "&" + incomingSearch;
        }
       
        this.location.replaceState( uid.routeConfig.path+ searchURL);
```

If my url is like

```
http://localhost:4200/#/women?occasion=cozy
```

The `window.location.search` returns empty

If I remove # from my URL I received the data

```
http://localhost:4200/women?occasion=cozy
```

The `window.location.search` returns **'?occasion=cozy'**

Any help is appreciated. I have looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45417393/angularjs-location-search-returns-empty-object) question as well but `$window.location.search` gives error though I have installed jquery.

Comment: try [window.location.hash](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/hash)

Comment: Thank you. However it return #women?ccasion=cozy.

Comment: Yes, but you got a value you weren't getting before and `window.location.hash.split('?')[1]` will get you the query string parameters.

Comment: Yes. I will have to tweak my code a little bit. Will publish an update.

Comment: may be this is similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63463068/cant-get-query-params-in-hashlocation-strategy-in-angular

Comment: The issue is cause because you set `useHash = true`. Instead of trying to solve an issue caused by this setting, wouldn't it be better to solve the routing issues you encounter with `useHash = false`?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that what you want is to modify query parameters of a URL containing a hash.

As you can see, adding `?key=value` or `&key=value` to the end of the URL is not the right way to add a query parameter (search parameter) to a URL, because a URL can contain a hash.

In the URL `http://example.com/?a=1&b=2#foo?c=3&d=4`, the query params are `{a: 1, b: 2}`, and the hash is `foo?c=3&d=4`. If you want to insert a query param into a URL, you need to do it before the hash.

`URL` objects make this convenient (this is from the Node.js REPL, but works in the browser as well):

```js
> url = new URL("https://localhost/?a=1&b=2#foo")
> url.hash = "bar"
> url.href
'https://localhost/?a=1&b=2#bar'
> url.searchParams.append("c", "something")
> url.href
'https://localhost/?a=1&b=2&c=something#bar'
>
> url.searchParams
URLSearchParams { 'a' => '1', 'b' => '2', 'c' => 'something' }
> url.searchParams.get('a')
'1'
>
```